# How to find out which version of Oracle is running?

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle database on a windows 2003 server which i can't start. How can i find out which version it is?

EDIT: Some of the oldest files are from 2003 and I dunno know if it's the original server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked HKLM\Software\Oracle?  I thought the Oracle version was held in the oracle homes section?

Answer (score 2):

Locate and launch the "Oracle Universal Installer" in your start menu.
Once it will be opened, click on the "Installed products" button (bottom left).

It will show you every Oracle product installed on this server and you will be able to view the version of every components.

You can also run the following command in a DOS prompt:

```
%oracle_home%\OPAtch\Opatch lsinventory
```

It will show you the list of the components installed in this Oracle Home and their version number.

Comment: I don't have the orcle universal installer in my start menu. Whats the programm name? Where is it located? The %oracle_home is not set on this server. I searched for OPatch under C:\programm files\oracle and d:\oracle (wheres the database located). Both no sucess. Some of the oldest files of this server is from 2003. but it could also be older than that... no documention.

Comment: On 10G and 11G, OUI is in %oracle_home%\oui\bin\setup.exe.
Oracle_home is the base folder of an oracle product. If you have an oracle.exe in D:\oracle\product\db_1\bin, then your oracle_home is D:\oracle\product\db_1\.

Answer (score 1):

run a query select * from v$version where banner like ‘Oracle%’;

**update
just noticed you had mentioned that you cannot start it.   Check in the application directory or the add/remove software from control panel may show the version number.

Comment: found the version in the a subfolder in the file EXPORT.LOG.